# error 80131904 requested by the login,the login is failed

Tags: c#, sql-server, winforms

*When I want to schedule my setup I get this error gives data recovery:*

**(0x80131904):cannot open database "myfile location" requested by the login,the login is failed.
login failed for user'myuser'**

*My guess is wrong with the connection string*

```
<connectionStrings>
    <add name="mehreparsian.Properties.Settings.lastmehreparsianConnectionString"
        connectionString="Data Source=(LocalDB)\v11.0;AttachDbFilename=|datadirectory|\lastmehreparsian.mdf;Integrated Security=True;Connect Timeout=30"
        providerName="System.Data.SqlClient" />
</connectionStrings>
```

Comment: well exactly that. you need to give it the correct credentials by specifying User ID and Password in the config file or give it trusted_connection=true to use Windows Authentication and or add the user account in the DB for the user you want to connect as

Comment: **I do not know how to do it off** @